# WordPress: first lower case p of each word not showing in main content area

Tags: wordpress

has anyone ever done the first lower case 'p' test on a standard wordpress page as appose to a post page?

example, write "lower case p test" ...

it works on a post pages but not on a standard page. i even put hardcoded html text in page.php and it removed the p.

i found a plugin and put this bit of code in and it didn't work...

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'capital_P_dangit' );
```

can anyone helps please?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this question is getting voted down...

I found this: http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/07/lowercase-p-wordpress-controversy/

For some background, see here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/08/lowercase-p-dangit

Also, is this the plugin you found? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remove-wordpress-to-wordpress-filter/

Comment: i tried all those and all the remove filters but none of them work... i'm desperate to get this fixed, help!!!!